# Links with Active State

Tags: html, mysql, css

This is my first time posting here. Any help is highly appreciated.

I am just trying to set an "Active" state into some links with IDs from Database. I would current active links to be a different style. I have set  different color here for testing:

Here is the code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM recipes where categoryID = '".$mycategory['categoryID']."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<ul class=\"nav_style\"><li><a href=\"?recipeID=".$row['recipeID']."\"> ".$row['recipeName']."</a></li></ul>";
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.nav_style a:link,
.nav_style a:visited   { color: #C0C0C0; text-decoration: none; }
.nav_style a:hover  { color: #58595B; text-decoration: none; }
.nav_style a:active  { color: #eee; text-decoration: none; }
```

Note that a part of URL is coming from Database. Will highly appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: explain your problem ?

Comment: Thank you guys fro reply and I am sorry for not being specific. The problem is that all links get color of "Visited" and "Link" Stats. I would like that current links to be a different color. I hope I was specific. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM recipes where categoryID = $mycategory['categoryID']";
```

remove your echo and paste this:

```
 echo '<ul class="nav_style"><li><a href="?recipeID="'.$row['recipeID'].'"" class="'.$row['<statte_column_name'].'">   '.$row['recipeName'].'</a></li></ul>';
```

state_column_name: write your state column name from your table whatever name you have given to this column.

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is not with PHP as I can get results, All of the links get the style of 'visited' state and I would to highlight current active links. On mouse click I can see the active color, but once I release it, turns again to "visited" color.

Comment: you can provide dynamic class name to the link and set different color with each class through css , i already define a class in anchor link just have a close look  on my code

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is you problem still I guess the below change will fix your peoblem.

Replace:

`echo "<ul class=\"nav_style\"><li><a href=\"?recipeID=".$row['recipeID']."\"> ".$row['recipeName']."</a></li></ul>";`

With:

`echo "<ul class="nav_style"><li><a href=\"?recipeID=".$row['recipeID']."\"> ".$row['recipeName']."</a></li></ul>";`

I think those `\` in `<ul>`'s class are unnecessary and causing problem.